# cannot find myfille .module ERROR on chrome

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

im using cmd chrome to run my test.. its navigate directly to my page home.. then when i clicked for tabs to navigate another page it show error on my developer tools saying it cannot find module myname.module  .. but somestimes it can run sometimes its not.. its so annoying.. is it bug ?

heres my home.router.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
  path : '',
  component: HomePage,
  children : [

 { path: 'feed', loadChildren: '../feed/feed.module#FeedPageModule' },
 { path: 'tracker', loadChildren: '../tracker/tracker.module#TrackerPageModule' },
 { path: 'uploader', loadChildren: '../uploader/uploader.module#UploaderPageModule'},
      ]
   }
```

Comment: two possibilities 1) the wrong path inside loadChildren check it with current directory 2) Either no module inside each page...

Comment: when i use url localhost:/home/feed on url it shows this error.. but when i use localhost:/feed its works fine... it this that u mention the problem ?